# How do I check the version of python a module supports?

Tags: python, pypi

I was wondering if there is a generic way to find out if your version of `python` is supported by a specific module?

For example, let us say that I have `python 3.11` installed on my computer and I want to install the modules `biopython` and `lru-dict`. Going to their respective `pypi` entries [`biopython`](https://pypi.org/project/biopython/) shows this in their `Project description`:

> Python Requirements
>
> We currently recommend using Python 3.10 from http://www.python.org
>
> Biopython is currently supported and tested on the following Python implementations:
>
> Python 3.7, 3.8, 3.9, 3.10 and 3.11 – see http://www.python.org
>
> PyPy3.7 v7.3.5 – or later, see http://www.pypy.org

However, if we check the [`lru-dict`](https://pypi.org/project/lru-dict/) entry, their `Project description` does not mention Python requirements. I did eventually find out that `python 3.11` is not supported by finding a [`issue`](https://github.com/amitdev/lru-dict/issues/44) on their `github` page.

Is there a simpler way of finding this information out?

Comment: The PyPi page does not have a `Python :: 3.11` classifier, so you could assume that Python 3.11 is not supported.

Comment: On a _PyPI_ project page, in the left column (on desktop view, not mobile), there is a section called "*Meta*", and in this section there can be a "*Requires*" field, which should indicate what you want. Some projects document this field in there packaging code, so it appears on their PyPI page (like *biopython*), but some projects don't (like *lru-dict*). -- So for *biopython 1.81.1* we can see: "*Requires: Python >=3.7*". -- Trove classifiers are another way to document this that appears on the _PyPI_ page, but I find it is less reliable and less up-to-date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no generic way.

If the library has tests you can run them and check, but it might give you false positives as well as false negatives :shrug:

The lru-dict has this fragment in their setup.py, which is one of the places you can check for supported versions:

```
        'Programming Language :: C',
        'Programming Language :: Python :: 3',
        'Programming Language :: Python :: 3.7',
        'Programming Language :: Python :: 3.8',
        'Programming Language :: Python :: 3.9',
        'Programming Language :: Python :: 3.10',
        'Programming Language :: Python :: 3.11',
        'Programming Language :: Python :: Implementation :: CPython',
```

So as you can see, I don't think they knew about the issue.

Comment: The [`requires_python`](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/specifications/core-metadata/#requires-python) field is important as well (if not more important).

Answer (score 4):

If you go to the `https://pypi.org/pypi/PACKAGE_NAME/json` address, you will receive complete information about Python PACKAGE_NAME in JSON format. For example, to view information about `lru-dict` open https://pypi.org/pypi/lru-dict/json link, Then you can extract the necessary information from it.

To see the Python version that PACKAGE_NAME is supported, I wrote this code, I hope it suits you.

```
import json
import pprint
from urllib import request

package_name = 'lru-dict'

with request.urlopen(f'https://pypi.org/pypi/{package_name}/json') as response:
    data = json.loads(response.read())
    pprint.pprint(data['info']['classifiers'])
```

Output:

```
 ['Development Status :: 5 - Production/Stable',
 'Intended Audience :: Developers',
 'License :: OSI Approved :: MIT License',
 'Operating System :: OS Independent',
 'Operating System :: POSIX',
 'Programming Language :: C',
 'Programming Language :: Python :: 2',
 'Programming Language :: Python :: 3',
 'Programming Language :: Python :: 3.10',
 'Programming Language :: Python :: 3.6',
 'Programming Language :: Python :: 3.7',
 'Programming Language :: Python :: 3.8',
 'Programming Language :: Python :: 3.9',
 'Programming Language :: Python :: Implementation :: CPython',
 'Topic :: Software Development :: Libraries :: Python Modules']
```

In addition to viewing the supported Python version, you can also get other information such as the Python version required for each release, package description, author's name, etc.

Comment: The [`requires_python`](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/specifications/core-metadata/#requires-python) field is important as well (if not more important).

Answer (score 1):

As @sinoroc said, the way to check supported versions of python is using the `requires_python` field. this is the way the author of a package would indicate his package works with which versions of python.
Any other check is nice, but not definite.

see [this link](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/specifications/core-metadata/#requires-python) he provided to understand the metadata of a package regarding python version support.

from [python official docs](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/tutorials/packaging-projects/#configuring-metadata)

> requires-python gives the versions of Python supported by your
> project. Installers like pip will look back through older versions of
> packages until it finds one that has a matching Python version.